# Select multiple cell values of same column into another cells whose next column values contain some specific value

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I Have some values with tags and I want to print/select those values corresponding to those tags when we select a tag in the dropdown menu

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate how you tried to solve this [ask]

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to paste this formula into **C2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B; G:H; 2; 0)))
```

---

if that is not what you seek then paste this into **C2** cell instead:

```
=FILTER(H:H; G:G=B2)
```